# What do you call this: "unsigned int a_bit : 1;"? Is there use outside of bit fields?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

So I was working with bit fields, when I started thinking that when you create a bit field, for example

```
struct bit_field{
  unsigned int just_a_bit : 1;
  unsigned int five_bits  : 5;
  unsigned int            : 3; //Fill to 8 bits
}
```

You use `unsigned int variable : bits;`, what is this called (so I can search it)? Can this be used outside of creating bit fields, and would there be any point in doing so?

For clarity, by "this" I mean using colon with size in bits after the variable name whilst creating a variable.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: So wait, I thought the entire struct was called bit field, but it's actually the `unsigned int just_a_bit : 1;` that's called a bit field?

Comment: No a struct is a struct.  the thing inside the struct is called a bit field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members *are* bitfields.

The encapsulating class is still just a class.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. This was the source of my confusion

Answer (score 4):

That is simply called a "bit-field". It's only allowed within a struct (or a union, though it's of [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326460/is-it-valid-to-use-bit-fields-with-union) use in a union).